# Error in hyperref package

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to color all links by using this option:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue,breaklinks,draft=false]{hyperref}
```

When compiling my .tex file, I get the error

```
Package keyval error: allcolors undefined
```

How do I rectify this.

Comment: From documentation: *Note that all color names must be defined before use, following the normal system of the
standard LaTeX `color` package*. So are you loading some color package before? Or is it not necessary?

Comment: Even after loading the color package, I get the same error.

Comment: I get no error with that line using `hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX` If you get an error please make state which version of hyperref you have

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Thanks for  that hint, I have 2007/02/07 v6.75r installed. How can I update to the new version. Is it the same process as mentioned in CTAN website?

Comment: most people these days just use miktex or texlive and let the package managers of those systems just update the entire tex tree as needed, but you can of course just get the file from ctan "by hand" and place it in your tex tree. We have several answers on site about installing packages, hyperref does not have any special requirements, no fonts etc just the plain text tex macro files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is due to outdated software; the version of hyperref used doesn't support the option.